# insertWithOnConflict making Columns null

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following code to update or insert database, where q_id is my primary key

```
public long updateResponse(int response, int q_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        long id = 0;



        contentValues.put(VivzHelper.Q_ID, q_id);
        contentValues.put(VivzHelper.QUESTION_RESPONSE, response);
        id =  db.insertWithOnConflict(VivzHelper.TABLE_QUESTION_TEXT, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        if(id==-1)
        Log.d("failed", "failed"+response);
        else
        Log.d("success","success"+response);
        return id;
    }
```

Above code is updating/inserting QUESTION_RESPONSE but making all other column in that row as null in table.. Help

Answer (score 0):

> Above code is updating/inserting QUESTION_RESPONSE but making all other column in that row as null in table

That's what the "replace" conflict resolution does. If the insert would result in a conflict, the conflicting rows are first deleted and only then is the new row inserted. `NULL` is the default default value for a column.

If you need to retain other column data in the row, use an `UPDATE` query. For example, to update the response column to the row with the specified id:

```
contentValues.put(VivzHelper.QUESTION_RESPONSE, response);
db.update(VivzHelper.TABLE_QUESTION_TEXT, contentValues,
    VivzHelper.Q_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(q_id) });
```

Comment: Thanks, but Can you show me a exapme where i can do update if exist else insert statement without making other colums null.